# How can I get all character until EOF with input() function in flex lexer?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I tried to use flex below.

```
<MOD1>{INFBLK_START} {
   int c = input(pp->scaninfo);
   while(c != EOF){
     //....save the character.
     c = input(pp->scaninfo);
   }
   return BLOCK;
}
```

but the code gives segment fault signal when I run those code.
the code crashed in yy_get_next_buffer function, where lex state is YY_END_OF_BUFFER.

How can I get all characters to EOF safely?

Comment: What is `pp->scaninfo`? Normally, `input()` takes no arguments.

Comment: @rici pp->scaninfo is a instance of yyscan_t. I use reentrant option in flex file. so the function argument will be different from non-reentrant one. Other rules in the file has been tested well, it will not make a problem. The only problem is caused by EOF reading.

Comment: OK. Do you define `yywrap` or do you specify `%option noyywrap`? (And if you define it, please add it to your question.)

Comment: @rici Yes, I have defined %option noyywrap.

Comment: OK, that exhausts the obvious ideas (or at least the ones which seeme obvious to me). You'll need to provide more code -- at a minimum, your setup code and `<<EOF>>` rules, if any -- and it wouldn't hurt to document the version of `bison` and precise command-line flags/options settings. Of course, it's always possible that you've got a buffer overrun or double-free in the elided code in that action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rici, I have finished this myself by changing the flex rules as below.

```
<MOD1>{INFBLK_START} {
    //malloc memory.
    BEGIN MOD2;
}
<MOD2>.|\n{
    //return each char and record them in bison code.
}
<MOD2><<EOF>>{
    yyterminate();
}
```

This is one way to get all charactors until EOF.

However there is a considerable shortage. The lexer should send every single char to parser with a function call, which will cost too much when the number of chars are very large.